# how to detect double clicks in MouseInput in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, double-click

How can I catch when user double clicks on the component?

```
 window.getComponent().addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(final java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                Xpcom.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });                
            }
        })

;
```

Comment: There is no need to use invokeLater in an event listener. All eventlistener code already runs on the event dispatch thread.

Comment: no need for the sake of doing stuff on the EDT, but might be a need to do it at-the-end of whatever is happening :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following post:

[Distinguish between a single click and a double click in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577424/distinguish-between-a-single-click-and-a-double-click-in-java)

Comment: Peter actually you were right. the problem is exactly that distinguishing between single click and double click. in my case it records 2 single clicks and then finally a double click. instead it should be just a single double click.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to use the [`getClickCount()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29) of `MouseEvent`

```
if (evt.getClickCount() == 2)  // double click
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Note that this will also trigger a single click. The only way that I know to handle that is to delay the reaction to the single click for a number of milliseconds and cancel it when the double click comes in.

Comment: @Peter - hmm ... what do you mean by "trigger a single click"? Anyway, a strong no for interfering with system behaviour: if the system decides that it is not a double, so be it.

Comment: This if statement will be executed on a double right click as well