# Can't filter MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED in AWT EventQueue

Tags: java, swing, mouseclick-event, mouse-listeners, awt-eventqueue

I need in my own AWT EventQueue filtering mouse double clicks, so I do:

```
public class AppEventQueue extends EventQueue
{
@Override
protected void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent event)
{
    super.dispatchEvent(event);
    if(event instanceof MouseEvent)
    {
        MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
        if(mouseEvent.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
}
```

Problem I have is that it looks that click with mouse is generating int value 16, MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED has value 500. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to check the id:

```
if (mouseEvent.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED {

}
```

Comment: work, thanks. don't understood why `code`mouseEvent.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED`code` generates 2 events: button pressed and button released, i think at this point it's very low-level and if i would check double click i need to implement my own timer and check if second click is going in defined time window.

Comment: hmm ... what do you mean? A clicked is _defined_ as being fired after a pressed-released-without-moving is done. So yeah, if you listen for pressed/released somewhere else you would receive two events (see the api doc of MouseEvent)

Comment: if i implement in app mouselistener i can check for mouseClicked(MouseEvent e), mousePressed(MouseEvent e) and mouseReleased(MouseEvent e). mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) is press-and-release-in-defined-time left button.