# swt - get max time between first and second click for doubleclick event

Tags: java, swt

Hello fellow Stackoverflownians,

I am in need of your assistance: I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, and am having issues with understanding how to get the maximum time allowed between clicks to constitute a double click.

**How can I get the OS time needed until a second click to constitute a "double click"?**

Or maybe this can be attained via SWT?

I've seen the AWT version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577424/distinguish-between-a-single-click-and-a-double-click-in-java).

> Integer timerinterval = (`Integer`)
>   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval");

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having trouble using the `Toolkit` approach?

Comment: I am not using awt in my project, but you've just pulled me out of a "retard"-moment.

Comment: I was assuming that it is impossible to mix with swt, but now I don't know why... checking.

Comment: So, does this value come from OS? Or is it just a default AWT?

Comment: SWT uses native controls so the value will be the OS value. Looking in the Mac code I don't think SWT ever needs to know what the actual value is.

Comment: But the code is from AWT. Does AWT also use native controls?

Comment: @VladIlie The necessary AWT code is included in the default JVM, so you can simply use it, even if you're using SWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the AWT solution will suffice.

Thanks guys!