# JTable: double-click should keep prior selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection, double-click

I have a `JTable` where I can select one or more cells. I also  want to react on double-click for doing some extra action for the selected cells. But the problem is, when the user double-clicks, the selection changes to the clicked cell. But I want to keep the prior selection on double-click, so I can handle the double-click for all selected cells.

**EDIT:**
Related to this question:
[Java : ignore single click on double click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548180/java-ignore-single-click-on-double-click)
But I hope, there is a better/easier solution for my case.

Comment: Beware - that's considered bad usability: the second click should augment the stuff done on the first, not something completely different

Comment: Better design would be to have a processing button like "Process Selected Cells" for the user to click on instead of using double click. Or you could use a popup menu to give the user different processing options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that on the first click the first event goes out. A bit later the second click might come or not. So the first click event does know nothing. As in the proposed solution a timer might do.

What also might do is on the first click to select nothing, but invoke a special selection event a bit later.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(myRunnable);
```

and on handling the double click/myRunnable the true selection. Timing might be unavoidable though.

Comment: Ok, seems that I can't avoid the timer.

Comment: At least a delay and time measurement is needed. myRunnable when too early invoked, could repeat itself with invokeLater. A timer seems easier.

Comment: But how do I stop the selection on the first click?

Comment: Then store the selection and on double click restore it. Not nice as this flickers the selection. Probably the selection can be suppressed by an other mean.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [setClickCountToStart()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#clickCountToStart) for XxxCellEditor, [I don't know something about your JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=setclickcounttostart)

Comment: This only changes the needed clicks for start editing, but doesn't touch the select-behaviour. Useless for my question.